find one positive integer solution for $x^3+101=y^2$ without computer
As the question asks, what is a quick way to find one positive integer solution for $x^3+101=y^2$ if you are in the exam room with only pen and paper and limited time?
About the question: it is from a question in the 2009 China Junior High School Maths Competition. (someone post on https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/114242326.html)
When I was working on this question, I tried Using mod on x,y.

nothing help when $\mod 2$

$(0,1,2)^3+101\mod 3 = (2,0,1)$
$(0,1,2)^2 \mod 3 = (0,1,1)$
so $x \mod 3 = 1,2$

$(0,1,2,3)^3+101\mod 4 = (1,2,1,0)$
$(0,1,2,3)^2 \mod 4 = (0,1,0,1)$
so $x \mod 4 = 0,2,3$

$(0,1,2,3,4)^3+101\mod 5 = (1,2,4,3,0)$
$(0,1,2,3,4)^2 \mod 5 = (0,1,4,4,1)$
so $x \mod 5 = 0,2,4$

$(0~5)^3+101\mod 6 = (5,0,1,2,3,4)$
$(0~5)^2 \mod 6 = (0,1,4,3,4,1)$
so $x \mod 6 = 1,2,4,5$

$(0~5)^3+101\mod 7 = (3,4,4,2,4,2,2)$
$(0~5)^2 \mod 7 = (0,1,4,2,2,4,1)$
so $x \mod 7 = 1,2,3,4,5,6$
this way cost a lot of time, and not help a lot

I recently took another stab at this topic when I was putting together my blog.
$x^3+1=y^2-100$
$(x+1)(x^2-x+1) = (y-10)(y+10)$
notice that $\gcd(y-10,y+10) = \gcd(y+10,20) \in [1,2,4,5,10,20]$
and $x^2-x+1=x(x-1)+1$ is always even
so $x+1 \mod 4 = 0, y \mod 4 = 0$
or $x+1 \mod 4 = 0, y \mod 4 = 2$
or $x+1 \mod 2 = 1, y \mod 2 = 1$

if $x+1 \mod 2 = 1, y \mod 2 = 1$
$(2k)^3+101=(2n+1)^2$
$8k^3+101=4n^2+4n+1$
$8k^3+101 \equiv 4n^2+4n+1 \mod 8$
$0+5 \equiv 4n(n+1)+1 \mod 8$
$5 \equiv 1 \mod 8$
impossible

if $x+1 \mod 4 = 0, y \mod 4 = 0$
$x=4k+3, y=4n$
$(4k+3)^3+101=(4n)^2$
$64k+9*16k^2+27*4k+27+101=16n^2$
$16k^3+9*4k^2+27k+32=4n^2$
$\rightarrow 4|k$
$x=16k_1+3,y=4n$

if $x+1 \mod 4 = 0, y \mod 4 = 2$
$x=4k+3, y=4n+2$
$(4k+3)^3+101=(4n+2)^2$
$64k+9*16k^2+27*4k+27+101=16n^2+16n+4$
$16k^3+9*4k^2+27k+32=4n^2+4n+1$
$\rightarrow 4| 27k-1$
$\rightarrow 4| (24+3)k-1$
$\rightarrow 4| 3k-1$
$\rightarrow k=4k_1+3$
$x=4(4k_1+3)+3=16k_1+15,y=4n+2$

in this way, i can only try $x=16k+3$ or $x=16k+15$
this will be faster.
I was wondering if there are some other ways to help with manual calculations?

Is it possible the question was copied incorrectly and simply asks for an integer solution? In that case $x=-1$ and $y=\pm 10$ work.

Extending your modulo $8$ calculation to modulo $16$ shows that we need $x$ to be congruent to either $3$ or $-1$ modulo $16$ (otherwise $x^3+101$ won't be a cubic residue modulo $16$). Given that $(x,y)=(-1,10)$ is an obvious solution, one might start experimenting with $x=16k-1$. And find that $(x,y)=(95,926)$ works, but here I used a calculator. When in junior high I might have had the determination to try it with paper & pencil, but...

Oh, you arrived at the same conclusion in the end. Modulo $32$ did not seem to give much further help (if I got it right, one of the four possibile lifts from modulo $16$ doesn't work, but that doesn't help much.

^^ $x^3+101$ won't be a quadratic residue modulo $16$, hopefully obviously :-)

You can keep going modulo increasing powers of two, Hensel lifting style.

@Mathematician42 it's positive integer, because it's the last question in 2009 contest, won't be that easy.

@JyrkiLahtonen thanks, for 'quadratic residue' and 'Hensel lifting style', i'm going to learn what it is.

@JyrkiLahtonen And then when I get $x \mod 16 \equiv 3 , -1$ this does reduce the amount of enumeration by a lot, and if we know ahead of time that the answer is 95, then we only need to enumerate 12 times. I also found $(-1,\pm 10)$, a non-positive solution. But I don't know if I can perform any transformations through it.

I haven't worked through this, but what struck me is that if you subtract $100$ from each side, you get the more tractable expression $x^3+1=y^2-100$

In the post you factored $x^3+1$ as $(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$, but it should be $(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$

@Sil thx, edited

Reducing modulo $9$ quickly gives $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ (also that $y \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 9$, but we won't use that fact).
On the other hand, reducing modulo $8$ gives $x^3 + 5 \equiv y^2 \pmod 8$, which implies that either

$x \equiv \phantom{-} 3 \pmod 8$ and $y \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, or
$x \equiv -1 \pmod 8$ and $y \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

In the latter case, combining our conditions gives $x \equiv -1 \pmod {24}$. Substituting $x = 24 a - 1, y = 4 b + 2$ in the original equation and reducing modulo $16$ gives that $a$ is even, say, $a = 2 c$, so
$x = 48 c - 1$. Substituting again and reducing modulo $32$ gives that $c$ is even, so $x = 96 d - 1$. (Repeating this process produces no more restrictions.) At this point, trying the smallest value, $d = 1$, yields the solution $$\boxed{(x, y) = (95, 926)} .$$
I don't see a clean way to dispense with the former case.
Remark The curve is elliptic, so it only has finitely many integer points. In fact, the solution we found is the only one: The following routine in Sage returns that the only integer points on the curve are $(-1, \pm 10)$ (which correspond to $d = 0$ above) and $(95, \pm 926)$.
E = EllipticCurve([0,0,0,0,101])
E.integral_points(both_signs=True)


i think combine $x\equiv 3 \pmod{8}$ and $x\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ will get $x = 11\pmod{24}$ , and the another half will get $x\equiv -1\pmod{24}$ How is this side eliminated?

I've tried combining $\mod 3$ and $\mod 8$, but haven't tried continuing to substitute $\mod 16$ and $\mod 32$, which does help! Thanks a lot!

@YeXiaoRain Like I wrote in the answer, I don't see a clean way to eliminate the other case. One route is to use the fact that $y \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 9$, which implies that $y \equiv 36 b \pm 8$, substitute, and check the $\pm$ cases separately. We can show that both are impossible after a few iterations of working modulo $2^r$ for successive $r$.

Not sure if this is going to help, but since the problem has already been solved by Travis, I just wanted to remind you that equations of the form
$$y^2 = x^3 + k$$
were studied extensively by Mordell and hence they are called Mordell's equation. There is a lot of literature on Mordell's equation and in particular we know (due to Mordell) that for a non-zero $k$, there are at most finitely many integers solutions.
Some nice expositions on this include this, this, and this.
